# Share internet by 2nd lan?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, network-shares, lan

I have 2 machines.

1st machine had 2 of LAN.

1. IP: 192.168.1.101 (internet)
2. IP: 172.10.1.101

2nd machine had 1 of LAN.

1. IP: 172.10.1.102

I want to use internet on 2nd machine by using 1st machine's internet lan. How to be used?

Answer (score 0):

Internet connection sharing is a windows feature that enables you to share your PC’s internet connections with other devices.

- To set up the feature, open the Control Panel and navigate to “Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Centre”.
- On the left pane click the “Change adapter settings” link to configure your connections.
- Right-click your internet connection and go to “Properties”.
- This will open a new network properties pop-up dialogue. Switch to the “Sharing” tab and check the box to allow other users to connect to the internet through your computer.

For more details about how to share an internet connection, please refer to the following link:

[How to Share an Internet Connection](https://www.wikihow.com/Share-an-Internet-Connection#Video)